# Return other value on class initialization

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm trying to learn OOPD principles, but there's a thing that annoys/confuses me and I can't seem to get my head around it.

Let's say I got an **App** class like this *(this makes a new instance from express to be used elsewhere)*:

```js
import { default as express, Application } from 'express';
import { default as helmet } from "helmet";
import { default as cors } from "cors";

export class App {
    public app: Application;

    constructor() {
      this.app = express();
      this.app.use(helmet());
      this.app.use(cors());
    }
}
```

and a **Server** class which uses the **App** class like here *(which is a singleton because it's used everywhere in the application but I've simplified it below)*:

```js
import { Server as httpServer, createServer } from 'http';
import { App } from './app';

export class Server {
  private _app: App;
  private _server: httpServer;

  private constructor(port: number) {
    this._app = new App();
    this._server = createServer(this._app.app); // <-- this annoys me
  }
}
```

I have to re-type the variable names all the time if I want to get the correct instance, it just looks ugly and like it shouldn't be that way. Cant I just return a new instance from express? Basically I want to convert this code into the desired classes:

```js
import { default as express } from "express";
import { default as helmet } from "helmet";
import { default as cors } from "cors";
import { createServer } from "http";

const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

export const server = createServer(app);

server.listen(4000);
```

The only thing I basically need from the **App** class is the `app` variable, so if I call `const app = new App()` I would like to have a new instance of express returned instead of typing `const app = new App().app`

Comment: There is no point in any of that being in classes. Also they're tightly coupled - don't create instances of collaborators in constructors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: What else are you looking for? You've turned five lines of code that were fine into fifteen that *you think are awkward*. Just don't do that.

Comment: I always thought that if you were to use classes you should use classes everywhere, for example an initalization script should be classes too

Comment: No, there's no need to do that. This is from Python, but applies here too (you don't even have the method other than `__init__`/`constructor`): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0